# Nesting ng-bootstrap tabs (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to nest a ng-bootstrap tab widget, but the content of the nested tab isn't shown properly. The moment I click on a nested tab, the content itself disappears.

[Minimal demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gu36tzIlg35DNikjR8kt?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

This is the view code:

```
            <ngb-tabset>
              <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
                <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
                  {{ tab.title }}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                  {{ tab.content }}

                  <ngb-tabset>
                    <ngb-tab>
                      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
                        1
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                        1
                      </ng-template>
                    </ngb-tab>
                    <ngb-tab>
                      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
                        2
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                        2
                      </ng-template>
                    </ngb-tab>
                    <ngb-tab>
                      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
                        3
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                        3
                      </ng-template>
                    </ngb-tab>
                  </ngb-tabset>

                </ng-template>
              </ngb-tab>
            </ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: what is the expected view? can you add a wireframe?

Comment: Well, I think it's clear enough. I want a nested tabs widget, which means that each tab of level 1 should have a tab widget with it's own tabs.

Comment: @alexandernst this is wiered, I'd recommend to add bug in their official github repo. I can see you already added [comment](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1433) there :D

Comment: @PankajParkar is right. I tried doing this. and its a bug of ng-bootstrap. will try fixing it. help Pankaj

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

Angular `4.3.6` contains a fix for this issue.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1433#issuecomment-325104017

**Previous version**

It's a bug.

Possible workaround might be having additional template like:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      {{ tab.title }}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      {{ tab.content }}
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerTabset"></ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>


<ng-template #innerTabset>
  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab>
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        1
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        1
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab>
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        2
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        2
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab>
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        3
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        3
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</ng-template>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tjw2eHIAxoIdNv5Wc1H9?p=preview)**

And you can generate any number of nested tabs like:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerTabset; context: { $implicit: tabs }"></ng-container>

<ng-template #innerTabset let-tabs>
  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        {{ tab.title }}
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        {{ tab.content }}
        <ng-template [ngIf]="tab.children">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerTabset; context: { $implicit: tab.children }"></ng-container>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</ng-template>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKz6p9fbQEl0uT75pLFO?p=preview)**

It works because each of embedded template has its own scope and angular doesn't mix query results

Answer (score 1):

For people who are facing the same problem.
Angular 4.3.6 contains a fix for this issue.

More information here : https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1433