# ng-bootstrap Tab inside another tab content is not working (angular 4)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a requirement where I need to create bunch of tabs inside another tab content. When I put set of tabs inside a tab, it show wired behavior.

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby
        sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>


      <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="tab12">
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.
              Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>

        <ngb-tab title="tab2 disabled">
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.
              Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
      </ngb-tabset>

    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.
      <p>Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo
        nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa
        terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby
        sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nw9utaWLYwmbhQW2OMLb?p=preview

In the plunker the tabs inside the first tab content will not be visible until you click in the heading of the tab and if you will click another tab then the child tabs will not be visible any more.

- Angular: 4.1.3
- ng-bootstrap: 1.0.0-alpha.26
- Bootstrap: 4.0.0-alpha.6

Answer (score 0):

I think some instances like `TemplateRef` are mixed in tabs when you use them as direct child. I would use `ngTemplateOutlet` to do it working:

```html
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Some content</p>

     <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerTabset"></ng-container>
  </ngb-tab>
  ...
</ngb-tabset>

<ng-template #innerTabset>
  <ngb-tabset>
    ... tabs content
  </ngb-tabset>
</ng-template>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y81t5SXKlLFxmRe41JCT?p=preview)**

See also

- [Nesting ng-bootstrap tabs (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718907/nesting-ng-bootstrap-tabs-angular-2)